# How to get a codeblock in a tool?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool

I wrote a script in ArcGIS Pro Notebook. It runs there perfectly. Now I try to create a tool with the script. ArcGIS has problems to read my "codeblock" in CalculateField correctly. I think it is bothered by the form of the comment. I already tried "\ (backslash)" as a simple line break in a string with no "#" comments in the codeblock, that didn't work because of the indentation rules. I also try the comment in "([...])" and it didnt work. Does anyone have an idea how I can make the codeblock understandable for the ArcGIS Pro Python Intepreter? Here is my snipplet:

````
```
spalteAGSName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) #GetParameterAsText(0)-(2) is before
spalteHausnummerVon = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
spalteHausnummerBis = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)

inTable = tabelleName
fieldName = "FALL"
expression = f"fallkalk({spalteAGSName}, {spalteHausnummerVon}, {spalteHausnummerBis})"
codeblock = """
def fallkalk(agsn,sthnr,endhnr):
    f = "F" #fehlerhafter Wert
    s1h = "S1H" #Straße hat nur ein Haus
    sges = "SGES" #Straße gesamt
    svon = "SVON" #Hausnummern haben eindeutigen Anfang und uneindeutiges Ende
    svonbis = "SVONBIS" #Hausnummern grenzen einen Bereich ein
    if agsn is None:
        return f
    elif sthnr == endhnr and sthnr is not None:
        return s1h
    elif agsn is not None and sthnr is None:
        return sges
    elif sthnr is not None:
        if endhnr == 9997 or endhnr == 9998 or endhnr == 9999:
            if sthnr == 0 or sthnr == 1 or sthnr == 2:
                return sges
            else:
                return svon
        return svonbis
"""
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inTable, fieldName, expression, "PYTHON3", codeblock)
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the error. The input are column names and must be bracketed with "!". Here is the correct code snippet:

```
    spalteAGSName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) 
    spalteHausnummerVon = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
    spalteHausnummerBis = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
    
    arcpy.AddMessage(spalteAGSName)
    
    spalteAGSName = "!" + spalteAGSName + "!"
    spalteHausnummerVon = "!" + spalteHausnummerVon + "!"
    spalteHausnummerBis = "!" + spalteHausnummerBis + "!"
    inTable = tabelleName
    fieldName = "FALL"
    expression = f"fallkalk({spalteAGSName}, {spalteHausnummerVon}, {spalteHausnummerBis})"
    codeblock = """
    def fallkalk(agsn,sthnr,endhnr):
        f = "F" #fehlerhafter Wert
        s1h = "S1H" #Straße hat nur ein Haus
        sges = "SGES" #Straße gesamt
        svon = "SVON" #Hausnummern haben eindeutigen Anfang und uneindeutiges Ende
        svonbis = "SVONBIS" #Hausnummern grenzen einen Bereich ein
        if agsn is None:
            return f
        elif sthnr == endhnr and sthnr is not None:
            return s1h
        elif agsn is not None and sthnr is None:
            return sges
        elif sthnr is not None:
            if endhnr == 9997 or endhnr == 9998 or endhnr == 9999:
                if sthnr == 0 or sthnr == 1 or sthnr == 2:
                    return sges
                else:
                    return svon
            return svonbis
    """
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(inTable, fieldName, expression, "PYTHON3", codeblock)
```